# How to add data to an IEnumerable - Table With related data - MudBlazor

Tags: c#, datatable, blazor, ienumerable, mudblazor

Simply put I want to add more rows to the table. I have recreated my issue here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQdvvwjdZHabpkB

I also have a textbox which allows the user to apply a filter to the data. E.g. When "Harry" is entered then only rows where the Name contains "Harry" should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

**IEnumerable** does not allow record manipulation (add, remove).

You need to change the type from IEnumerable to IList.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Concat to produce a new IEnumerable:

```
people = people.Concat(new []{ new Person()});
```

However, this is not a great approach if adding many items. You are most likely better of just declaring the the property as a `List<T>` to make adding items trivial. If needed you can keep an private field with the actual collection type, and a public property that returns a `IEnumerable<T>`. Also see [ImmutableCollections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/net-framework-immutable-collections) if you want to ensure collections never changes.